# drawing matches using opencv for android

Tags: android, opencv, sift

I'm working with sift using opencv sdk for android
I'm facing difficulties in drawing matches between two images using the

> Feature2d.drawMatches()

whenever I run the app it goes through all the steps but stopped when reaching the draw function.

Here's the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    System.loadLibrary("nonfree");
}

private ImageView imageView;

private FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);
DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor=DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);
DescriptorMatcher descriptorMatcher= DescriptorMatcher.create(3);

Bitmap inputImage;
Bitmap inputImage2;
Bitmap out;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Hiii",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

    inputImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.object);
    inputImage2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.objecttest);
    out = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     sift();
}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}


public void sift() {

    Mat rgba = new Mat();
    Mat rgba2 = new Mat();
    Mat desc=new Mat();
    Mat desc2=new Mat();
    MatOfDMatch matches=new MatOfDMatch();
    Mat output=new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(inputImage, rgba);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(inputImage2, rgba2);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(out, output);

    MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba2, rgba2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    detector.detect(rgba, keyPoints);
    detector.detect(rgba2, keyPoints2);

    descriptorExtractor.compute(rgba,keyPoints,desc);
    descriptorExtractor.compute(rgba2,keyPoints2,desc2);
    descriptorMatcher.match(desc,desc2,matches);

    Features2d.drawMatches(rgba,keyPoints,rgba2,keyPoints2,matches,output);
       Utils.matToBitmap(output, out);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(out);
    }


  }
```

*I also need to know whether sift is the best choice for the use of detecting complicated objects in real time?*

*Edit 1*: I notice now that I'm getting the following errors

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows)
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x12ce08e0 in tid 9971

Comment: Do you get an error when it stops ?

Comment: yes actually I noticed that now, and I've updated the question with the error message

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved:**
the error I've mentioned was preventing the image from being displayed for some reason( maybe the difference of properties between the image view and the image we want to display **let's say the dimensions in some cases**
actually I'm not sure about the previous point but it was mentioned out there, and the solution was to set the image view to be dynamically resized according to the image but that didn't work for me)
My problem was solved by replacing these instructions:

```
 Features2d.drawMatches(rgba,keyPoints,rgba2,keyPoints2,matches,output);
 Utils.matToBitmap(output, out);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(out);
```

with the following:

```
Scalar RED = new Scalar(255,0,0);
Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);
MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
 Features2d.drawMatches(rgba,keyPoints,rgba2,keyPoints2,matches,output,GREEN, RED,  drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

Bitmap imageMatched = Bitmap.createBitmap(output.cols(), output.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);//need to save bitmap
Utils.matToBitmap(output, imageMatched);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageMatched);
```

I didn't actually get the difference, so further help describing this will be so helpful, but hope this can temporarily help people having the same problem